# How do I add a blank space in the pageblock title section

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocksection, header

I have tried

```
.pbTitle {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
```

and

```
 &nbsp;
```

These are not working see my example what I want to achieve:

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection id="section1" title="Accountname:{!a.name} [space------space]AccountID:{!a.id}" columns="5" >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the header facet and place custom styles on the inner component. This means you don't need to rely on specific class names that Salesforce uses for its CSS. Here's an example:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:pageBlock tabStyle="Account">
        <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" >
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <span style="white-space: pre">Hello              World</span>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: this worked but cant seem to get any text in between:  <apex:facet name="header"><apex:outputField value="{Accountnaam:}"/><apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.Edit, a.Id)}"> {!a.name} </apex:outputLink> </apex:facet>

Comment: @Jenssen You didn't specify a span tag, as demonstrated in this answer.

Comment: I tried the span with text that works nice. If I use the span with the url in the above description i doen see the url I would like to know if I could get an url with a description in the  apex:facet?

Comment: @Jenssen It should work, although you could also use a normal link `<a href=...`.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking to preserve the white spaces and to achieve that you need to use

```
white-space: pre;
```

> Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the `<pre>` tag in HTML

And, you can use following CSS to apply it in Visualforce.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .pbSubheader h3 {
        white-space: pre;
    }
</style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can do this, but of course, this would affect every page block section title header on the page, which may be undesirable.

Comment: @sfdcfox is it possible to target the id of the specific pageblocksection?

Comment: @Jenssen Yes, you can, it just takes more CSS. Or, you could use a facet, as I suggested.